# How to access mac os x microphone inside docker container?

Tags: python, docker, audio, microphone

I am running a docker container with the python code that records the sound for few seconds using the host MacBook Pro build in microphone.

Part of my challenge is to determine how to provide access/share Macbook Pro microphone inside the Docker container. Most of the existing questions on stack overflow or elsewhere provide solutions for Linux based distros but I don't have much luck to do the same with mac os.

The OS version details:

```
System Version: macOS 10.14.2 (18C54)
Kernel Version: Darwin 18.2.0
```

Docker:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:39 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

The python code is simple and working as expected on the host.

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
fs = 48000
duration=5
rec = sd.rec(int(duration * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=1, blocking=True)
print(rec)
```

Here is the docker file:

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install libasound-dev
RUN apt-get -y install portaudio19-dev

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY AudioRecordingTest.py ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "./AudioRecordingTest.py" ]
```

```
docker build -t audiorecording:1.0 .

docker run -it --rm --device --privileged=true DONT_KNOW_ABOUT_THIS_PART:/dev/snd  audiorecording:1.0
```

Ideally should able to mount/share the microphone as you do when Linux is the host. If not what are the other possible solutions?

```
docker run -it --rm --device --privileged=true DONT_KNOW_ABOUT_THIS_PART:/dev/snd  audiorecording:1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running the `pulseaudio` server on the host and connect to it from the docker.

You will need to build the docker with `pulseaudio` support:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    vorbis-tools \
    sox \
    alsa-utils \
    libasound2 \
    libasound2-plugins \
    pulseaudio \
    pulseaudio-utils \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then

1. Add `load-module module-native-protocol-tcp` to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
2. expose its address as environmental variable to docker with `-e`
3. authorize it's usage in the docker by copying cookie into the docker (or sharing it with `-v` option)
4. add access to the host device with `--device`

Then run

```
docker run -it \
           --device=/dev/snd \   
           -e PULSE_SERVER=host.docker.internal \
           -v ~/.config/pulse:/home/pulseaudio/.config/pulse \
  ... + other options you need
```

See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972510/how-to-set-alsa-default-device-to-pulseaudio-sound-server-on-docker), [this](https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/issues/85) and [this](https://volkanpaksoy.com/archive/2019/12/05/Using-Audio-in-Docker-Container/).

Comment: How can I get ~/.config/pulse folder? I have already install `pulseaudio` using homebrew but that directory doesn't exists.

Comment: You need not only install but also **run** `pulseaudio` server ;) Do it either by `brew services start pulseaudio` (and relogin)  or `pulseaudio --load=module-native-protocol-tcp --exit-idle-time=-1 --daemon`. After you start the server config directory would be created automatically.

Comment: Please note that latest docker changed `docker.for.mac.localhost` to `host.docker.internal`

Comment: I've faced some issue here when trying to run `pulseaudio --load=module-native-protocol-tcp --exit-idle-time=-1 --daemon`. I was downloading pulseaudio via homebrew and run exactly what you told but there's error:
`
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib/libgdbm.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/pulseaudio
  Reason: image not found
[1]    13266 abort      pulseaudio
`

Comment: Update, so i have try your method on my another computer. Pulseaudio seems to work well. However, the docker run command fails when adding device giving the following error: `docker: Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/snd": no such file or directory.`