# Where is the built-in microphone device on Mac OS?

Tags: docker, macos, microphone

### Problem

I would like to know how to specify Mac's built-in microphone in CLI. The purpose is to map the built-in microphone to a Docker container.

More precisely, I would like to know what to write in this ??? part: `docker run --device ???:/dev/snd`.

### Environment

Mac OS Monterey 12.3.1
Docker 4.4.2

### Commands I tried

1. I installed `pulseaudio` according to this answer. (This answer fails to explain how to specify the microphone device in `docker run --device`.)
   To be honest, I am not sure if `pulseaudio` affects this question.

[How to access mac os x microphone inside docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54702179/how-to-access-mac-os-x-microphone-inside-docker-container)

```
brew install pulseaudio
brew services start pulseaudio
```

2. I tried to find the built-in microphone using `ls`. The second answer in this page suggests two directories: `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/` and `/System/Library/Extensions/`.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47822/where-are-audio-device-files-in-osx

```
% ls -lha /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B Apr  3  2021 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel   192B May 14 10:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B Apr  3  2021 Background Music Device.driver
```

```
% ls -a /System/Library/Extensions/                 
.                           AppleRTC.kext
..                          AppleRemoteIOP.kext
AFKACIPCKext.kext                   AppleS5L8920XPWM.kext
AFTK_Kext.kext                      AppleS5L8930XUSB.kext
AGXFirmwareKextG11GRTBuddy.kext             AppleS5L8940XDWI.kext
AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy.kext             AppleS5L8940XI2C.kext
AGXFirmwareKextG13XRTBuddy.kext             AppleS5L8960XNCO.kext
AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64.kext               AppleS5L8960XUSB.kext
AGXG11G.kext                        AppleS8000AES.kext
AGXG13G.kext                        AppleS8000DWI.kext
AGXG13X.kext                        AppleSART.kext
AGXGPURawCounterBundle.bundle               AppleSDXC.kext
AGXMetal13_3.bundle                 AppleSEPGenericTransfer.kext
AGXMetal13_3_a.bundle                   AppleSEPHDCPManager.kext
AGXMetalA12.bundle                  AppleSEPKeyStore.kext
AGXMetalG13S_A0.bundle                  AppleSEPManager.kext
AGXMetalG13X.bundle                 AppleSMBIOS.kext
ALF.kext                        AppleSMBusController.kext
AMD10000Controller.kext                 AppleSMBusPCI.kext
AMD7000Controller.kext                  AppleSMC.kext
AMD8000Controller.kext                  AppleSMCLMU.kext
AMD9000Controller.kext                  AppleSMCRTC.kext
AMD9500Controller.kext                  AppleSPIMC.kext
AMDFramebuffer.kext                 AppleSPMI.kext
AMDMTLBronzeDriver.bundle               AppleSPMIPMU.kext
AMDRadeonServiceManager.kext                AppleSPU.kext
AMDRadeonVADriver.bundle                AppleSRP.kext
AMDRadeonVADriver2.bundle               AppleSSE.kext
AMDRadeonX4000.kext                 AppleSTDP2700.kext
AMDRadeonX4000GLDriver.bundle               AppleSamsungSPI.kext
AMDRadeonX4000HWServices.kext               AppleSamsungSerial.kext
AMDRadeonX5000.kext                 AppleSerialShim.kext
AMDRadeonX5000GLDriver.bundle               AppleSmartBatteryManager.kext
AMDRadeonX5000HWServices.kext               AppleSmartIO2.kext
AMDRadeonX5000MTLDriver.bundle              AppleStockholmControl.kext
AMDRadeonX5000Shared.bundle             AppleStorageDrivers.kext
AMDRadeonX6000.kext                 AppleSummitLCD.kext
AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer.kext              AppleSynopsysMIPIDSI.kext
AMDRadeonX6000GLDriver.bundle               AppleSynopsysUSB40XHCI.kext
AMDRadeonX6000HWServices.kext               AppleSynopsysUSBXHCI.kext
AMDRadeonX6000MTLDriver.bundle              AppleSystemPolicy.kext
AMDRadeonX6000Shared.bundle             AppleT6000.kext
AMDRawCounterPlugin.bundle              AppleT6000CLPCv3.kext
AMDShared.bundle                    AppleT6000DART.kext
AMDSupport.kext                     AppleT6000PCIeC.kext
AUC.kext                        AppleT6000PMGR.kext
Apple16X50Serial.kext                   AppleT6000SOCTuner.kext
AppleA7IOP.kext                     AppleT6001PMGR.kext
AppleACPIPlatform.kext                  AppleT6002CLPC.kext
AppleAHCIPort.kext                  AppleT600xPCIe.kext
AppleALSColorSensor.kext                AppleT8002USB.kext
AppleANELoadBalancer.kext               AppleT8006USB.kext
AppleANXDPTX.kext                   AppleT8010PMPFirmware.kext
AppleAOPAudio.kext                  AppleT8011PMPFirmware.kext
AppleAOPVoiceTrigger.kext               AppleT8011USB.kext
AppleAPIC.kext                      AppleT8015PMPFirmware.kext
AppleARMGIC.kext                    AppleT8020.kext
AppleARMIISAudio.kext                   AppleT8020DART.kext
AppleARMPMU.kext                    AppleT8020PMPFirmware.kext
AppleARMPlatform.kext                   AppleT8020SOCTuner.kext
AppleARMWatchdogTimer.kext              AppleT8020USB.kext
AppleAVD.kext                       AppleT8027.kext
AppleAVE2.kext                      AppleT8027CLPCv3.kext
AppleAVEBridge.kext                 AppleT8027PCIe.kext
AppleActuatorDriver.kext                AppleT8027PMGR.kext
AppleAfterburner.kext                   AppleT8027PMPFirmware.kext
AppleAudioClockLibs.kext                AppleT8027USB.kext
AppleAuthCP.kext                    AppleT8101.kext
AppleAvalancheErrorHandler.kext             AppleT8101AFT.kext
AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe.kext           AppleT8101USB.kext
AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac.kext            AppleT8103CLPCv3.kext
AppleBCMWLANCore.kext                   AppleT8103PCIe.kext
AppleBCMWLANCoreMac.kext                AppleT8103PCIeC.kext
AppleBSDKextStarter.kext                AppleT8103PMGR.kext
AppleBTM.kext                       AppleT8103USB.kext
AppleBacklight.kext                 AppleT8110DART.kext
AppleBacklightExpert.kext               AppleT8110PCIe.kext
AppleBiometricSensor.kext               AppleT8110PMGR.kext
AppleBiometricServices.kext             AppleT8301USB.kext
AppleBluetoothDebug.kext                AppleTCA6408GPIOIC.kext
AppleBluetoothDebugService.kext             AppleTCA7408GPIOIC.kext
AppleBluetoothModule.kext               AppleThunderboltDPAdapters.kext
AppleBluetoothMultitouch.kext               AppleThunderboltEDMService.kext
AppleBluetoothRemote.kext               AppleThunderboltIP.kext
AppleBusPowerController.kext                AppleThunderboltNHI.kext
AppleCSEmbeddedAudio.kext               AppleThunderboltPCIAdapters.kext
AppleCameraInterface.kext               AppleThunderboltUSBAdapters.kext
AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl.kext          AppleThunderboltUTDM.kext
AppleConvergedPCI.kext                  AppleTopCase.kext
AppleCredentialManager.kext             AppleTriStar.kext
AppleCycloneErrorHandler.kext               AppleTrustedAccessory.kext
AppleD1755PMU.kext                  AppleTwisterErrorHandler.kext
AppleD1815PMU.kext                  AppleTypeCPhy.kext
AppleD1881PMU.kext                  AppleUSBACM.kext
AppleD1946PMU.kext                  AppleUSBAudio.kext
AppleD1972PMU.kext                  AppleUSBCDC.kext
AppleD1974PMU.kext                  AppleUSBCommon.kext
AppleD2018PMU.kext                  AppleUSBDMM.kext
AppleD2045PMU.kext                  AppleUSBDeviceMux.kext
AppleD2089PMU.kext                  AppleUSBDeviceNCM.kext
AppleD2186PMU.kext                  AppleUSBDisplays.kext
AppleD2207PMU.kext                  AppleUSBECM.kext
AppleD2238PMU.kext                  AppleUSBEEM.kext
AppleD2255PMU.kext                  AppleUSBEthernet.kext
AppleD2257PMU.kext                  AppleUSBEthernetHost.kext
AppleD2333PMU.kext                  AppleUSBHSIC.kext
AppleD2346PMU.kext                  AppleUSBHostS5L8930X.kext
AppleD2365PMU.kext                  AppleUSBHostS5L8960X.kext
AppleD2400PMU.kext                  AppleUSBHostT7000.kext
AppleD2401PMU.kext                  AppleUSBHostT8002.kext
AppleD2422PMU.kext                  AppleUSBHostT8011.kext
AppleD2449PMU.kext                  AppleUSBHostT8020.kext
AppleD2460PMU.kext                  AppleUSBMike.kext
AppleDAPF.kext                      AppleUSBMultitouch.kext
AppleDCP.kext                       AppleUSBNCM.kext
AppleDCPDPDisplayProxy.kext             AppleUSBNetworking.kext
AppleDCPDPTXProxy.kext                  AppleUSBRealtek8153Patcher.kext
AppleDPDisplay.kext                 AppleUSBSerial.kext
AppleDPDisplayTCON.kext                 AppleUSBTopCase.kext
AppleDPRepeater.kext                    AppleUSBWCM.kext
AppleDPTX.kext                      AppleUSBiBridge.kext
AppleDiagnosticDataAccess.kext              AppleUpstreamUserClient.kext
AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly.kext          AppleVADriver.bundle
AppleDialogPMU.kext                 AppleVPBootPolicy.kext
AppleDiskImages2.kext                   AppleVPCredentialManager.kext
AppleDisplayCrossbar.kext               AppleVPKeyStore.kext
AppleDockChannel.kext                   AppleVirtIO.kext
AppleEFIRuntime.kext                    AppleVirtIOStorage.kext
AppleEffaceableBlockDevice.kext             AppleVirtualGraphics.kext
AppleEffaceableNOR.kext                 AppleVirtualPlatform.kext
AppleEffaceableStorage.kext             AppleVortexErrorHandler.kext
AppleEffaceableTDM.kext                 AppleXsanScheme.kext
AppleEmbeddedAccelerometer.kext             Apple_iSight.kext
AppleEmbeddedAudio.kext                 ArcMSR.kext
AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs.kext             AudioAUUC.kext
AppleEmbeddedBluetoothMultitouch.kext           AudioDMAController_T600x.kext
AppleEmbeddedLightSensor.kext               AudioDMAController_T8103.kext
AppleEmbeddedNewAccelerometer.kext          BCMWLANFirmware4355_Hashstore.kext
AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost.kext             BCMWLANFirmware4364_Hashstore.kext
AppleEmbeddedPCIE.kext                  BCMWLANFirmware4377_Hashstore.kext
AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasherDriver.kext     BCMWLANFirmware4378_Hashstore.kext
AppleEmbeddedTempSensor.kext                BCMWLANFirmware4387_Hashstore.kext
AppleEmbeddedTouchEEPROMDriver.kext         BootCache.kext
AppleEmbeddedUSB.kext                   BootPolicy.kext
AppleEmbeddedUSBHost.kext               BridgeAudioCommunication.kext
AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIPCI.kext                BridgeAudioController.kext
AppleEncryptedArchive.kext              BroadcomBluetooth20703USBTransport.kext
AppleEventLogHandler.kext               BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport.kext
AppleFAN53740.kext                  CSRBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport.kext
AppleFDEKeyStore.kext                   CellPhoneHelper.kext
AppleFIVRDriver.kext                    CoreAnalyticsFamily.kext
AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless.kext         CoreKDL.kext
AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib.kext             CoreStorage.kext
AppleFWAudio.kext                   CoreTrust.kext
AppleFileSystemDriver.kext              DCPAVFamilyProxy.kext
AppleFireStormErrorHandler.kext             DCPDPFamilyProxy.kext
AppleFirmwareKit.kext                   DCPMIPIProxy.kext
AppleFirmwareUpdateKext.kext                Dont Steal Mac OS X.kext
AppleGFXHDA.kext                    EAP-RSA.ppp
AppleGL3590FirmwareUpdater.kext             EncryptedBlockStorage.kext
AppleGPIOICController.kext              EndpointSecurity.kext
AppleGameControllerPersonality.kext         FairPlayIOKit.kext
AppleGraphicsControl.kext               HFS.kext
AppleGraphicsPowerManagement.kext           HFSEncodings.kext
AppleH10CameraInterface.kext                HFS_MacCentralEurRoman.kext
AppleH10PearlCameraInterface.kext           HFS_MacChineseSimp.kext
AppleH11ANEInterface.kext               HFS_MacChineseTrad.kext
AppleH13CameraInterface.kext                HFS_MacCyrillic.kext
AppleHDA.kext                       HFS_MacJapanese.kext
AppleHIDALSService.kext                 HFS_MacKorean.kext
AppleHIDKeyboard.kext                   IO80211Family.kext
AppleHIDKeyboardEmbedded.kext               IO80211FamilyLegacy.kext
AppleHIDMouse.kext                  IOACPIFamily.kext
AppleHIDTransport.kext                  IOAHCIFamily.kext
AppleHPET.kext                      IOATAFamily.kext
AppleHPM.kext                       IOAVBFamily.kext
AppleHSSPIHIDDriver.kext                IOAVFamily.kext
AppleHSSPISupport.kext                  IOAccelerator2D.plugin
AppleHV.kext                        IOAcceleratorFamily2.kext
AppleHighVoltageCharger.kext                IOAccessoryManager.kext
AppleIISController.kext                 IOAccessoryPortUSB.kext
AppleIPAppender.kext                    IOAudio2Family.kext
AppleIRController.kext                  IOAudioFamily.kext
AppleImage4.kext                    IOBDStorageFamily.kext
AppleInputDeviceSupport.kext                IOBiometricFamily.kext
AppleIntelBDWGraphics.kext              IOBluetoothFamily.kext
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer.kext           IOBluetoothHIDDriver.kext
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsGLDriver.bundle            IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport.kext
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsMTLDriver.bundle           IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport.kext
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsVADriver.bundle            IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport.kext
AppleIntelBDWGraphicsVAME.bundle            IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport.kext
AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer.kext           IOBluetoothPacketLogger.kext
AppleIntelCFLGraphicsVAME.bundle            IOBluetoothSerialManager.kext
AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement.kext           IOBufferCopyController.kext
AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient.kext         IOBufferCopyEngineFamily.kext
AppleIntelFramebufferAzul.kext              IOCDStorageFamily.kext
AppleIntelGraphicsShared.bundle             IOCECFamily.kext
AppleIntelHD5000Graphics.kext               IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily.kext
AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle         IODARTFamily.kext
AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsMTLDriver.bundle        IODVDStorageFamily.kext
AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsVADriver.bundle         IODisplayPortFamily.kext
AppleIntelHSWVA.bundle                  IOFireWireAVC.kext
AppleIntelICLGraphics.kext              IOFireWireFamily.kext
AppleIntelICLGraphicsGLDriver.bundle            IOFireWireSBP2.kext
AppleIntelICLGraphicsMTLDriver.bundle           IOFireWireSerialBusProtocolTransport.kext
AppleIntelICLGraphicsVADriver.bundle            IOGPUFamily.kext
AppleIntelICLLPGraphicsFramebuffer.kext         IOGraphicsFamily.kext
AppleIntelICLLPGraphicsVAME.bundle          IOHDCPFamily.kext
AppleIntelKBLGraphics.kext              IOHDIXController.kext
AppleIntelKBLGraphicsFramebuffer.kext           IOHIDFamily.kext
AppleIntelKBLGraphicsGLDriver.bundle            IOImageLoader.kext
AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver.bundle           IOKitRegistryCompatibility.kext
AppleIntelKBLGraphicsVADriver.bundle            IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP.kext
AppleIntelKBLGraphicsVAME.bundle            IOMobileGraphicsFamily.kext
AppleIntelLpssDmac.kext                 IONDRVSupport.kext
AppleIntelLpssGspi.kext                 IONVMeFamily.kext
AppleIntelLpssI2C.kext                  IONetworkingFamily.kext
AppleIntelLpssI2CController.kext            IOPCIFamily.kext
AppleIntelLpssSpiController.kext            IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext
AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon.kext               IOReportFamily.kext
AppleIntelLpssUARTv0.kext               IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily.kext
AppleIntelLpssUARTv1.kext               IOSCSIParallelFamily.kext
AppleIntelMCEReporter.kext              IOSMBusFamily.kext
AppleIntelPCHPMC.kext                   IOSerialFamily.kext
AppleIntelSKLGraphics.kext              IOSkywalkFamily.kext
AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer.kext           IOSlaveProcessor.kext
AppleIntelSKLGraphicsGLDriver.bundle            IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily.kext
AppleIntelSKLGraphicsMTLDriver.bundle           IOStorageFamily.kext
AppleIntelSKLGraphicsVADriver.bundle            IOStreamFamily.kext
AppleIntelSKLGraphicsVAME.bundle            IOSurface.kext
AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking.kext         IOTextEncryptionFamily.kext
AppleInterruptController.kext               IOThunderboltFamily.kext
AppleInterruptControllerV2.kext             IOTimeSyncFamily.kext
AppleJPEGDriver.kext                    IOUSBDeviceFamily.kext
AppleKeyStore.kext                  IOUSBFamily.kext
AppleLMBacklight.kext                   IOUSBHostFamily.kext
AppleLPC.kext                       IOUSBMassStorageDriver.kext
AppleLSIFusionMPT.kext                  IOUserEthernet.kext
AppleLightningErrorHandler.kext             IOUserSerial.kext
AppleM2ScalerCSC.kext                   IOVideoFamily.kext
AppleM68Buttons.kext                    InvalidateHmac.kext
AppleMCA2_T600x.kext                    KernelRelayHost.kext
AppleMCA2_T8020.kext                    KextAudit.kext
AppleMCA2_T8027.kext                    L2TP.kext
AppleMCA2_T8103.kext                    Libm.kext
AppleMCCSControl.kext                   LightweightVolumeManager.kext
AppleMCDP29XX.kext                  NVMeSMARTLib.plugin
AppleMCDP29XXUpdateSupport.kext             NVSMU.kext
AppleMCP89RootPortPM.kext               OSvKernDSPLib.kext
AppleMIDIBluetoothDriver.plugin             PPP.kext
AppleMIDIFWDriver.plugin                PPPoE.kext
AppleMIDIIACDriver.plugin               PromiseSTEX.kext
AppleMIDIRTPDriver.plugin               Quarantine.kext
AppleMIDIUSBDriver.plugin               RTBuddy.kext
AppleMatch.kext                     RTBuddyV3.kext
AppleMesaSEPDriver.kext                 SEPHibernation.kext
AppleMetalOpenGLRenderer.bundle             SMARTLib.plugin
AppleMikeyHIDDriver.kext                SMCMotionSensor.kext
AppleMobileApNonce.kext                 Sandbox.kext
AppleMobileDispH11G.kext                System.kext
AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP.kext                UVCService.kext
AppleMobileDispH13G-DFR.kext                acfs.kext
AppleMobileDispH13G.kext                acfsctl.kext
AppleMobileDispT600X-DCP.kext               afpfs.kext
AppleMobileDispT600X.kext               apfs.kext
AppleMobileFileIntegrity.kext               asp_tcp.kext
AppleMultiFunctionManager.kext              autofs.kext
AppleMultiFunctionManagerMac.kext           cd9660.kext
AppleMultitouchDriver.kext              cddafs.kext
AppleNANDConfigAccess.kext              corecapture.kext
AppleOLYHAL.kext                    corecrypto.kext
AppleOLYHALMac.kext                 eficheck.kext
AppleOnboardSerial.kext                 exfat.kext
ApplePIODMA.kext                    iPodDriver.kext
ApplePMGR.kext                      lifs.kext
ApplePMP.kext                       mcxalr.kext
ApplePMPFirmware.kext                   msdosfs.kext
ApplePVPanic.kext                   ntfs.kext
AppleParavirtGPU.kext                   pmtelemetry.kext
AppleParavirtGPUIOGPUFamily.kext            pthread.kext
AppleParavirtGPUMetal.bundle                smbfs.kext
AppleParavirtGPUMetalIOGPUFamily.bundle         tmpfs.kext
AppleParavirtIOSurface.kext             triggers.kext
ApplePassthroughPPM.kext                udf.kext
ApplePerfPolicyControllers.kext             vecLib.kext
ApplePlatformEnabler.kext               watchdog.kext
AppleProResHW.kext                  webcontentfilter.kext
AppleRAID.kext                      webdav_fs.kext
```

3. I saw the names of the files and tried to use `/System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext`. It seems `.kext` files are not device nodes.

```
% docker run --name testcontainer -it --device /System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext:/dev/snd -e PULSE_SERVER=host.docker.internal -v ~/.config/pulse:/root/.config/pulse testimage
docker: Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext": not a device node.
```

Comment: Since Docker containers on MacOS run in a hidden Linux VM, you probably can't directly access hardware devices.  It might be easier to run this program outside a container directly on the host.